# MySQL processes killed when tmp space maxed out

Tags: mysql

I recently just moved my `tmp` directory to a 50GB ramdisk. Processes seem to be running fast but I had a few large temp tables created which filled up the 50GB. This caused **all** processes to be killed.

```
mysql> show variables like '%tmp%';
+-------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name     | Value       |
+-------------------+-------------+
| max_tmp_tables    | 32          |
| slave_load_tmpdir | /run/mysqld |
| tmp_table_size    | 16777216    |
| tmpdir            | /run/mysqld |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

Is this normal? I've never noticed this happen before. Is there a way to have only the process filling up the `tmp` directory die and leave everything else running?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound normal - from my experience it should have only killed the process filling the tmpdir.

I did dig a bit and saw an old documented bug on it:  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69926 , but I guess it depends on which storage engine you're using and what version of mysql you're running.